# How to post value by javascript/ajax after added elements by dynamicly

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, element

i had success added elements  dynamicly by javascript for using in a form as a new lines.

the question is how can i post values from new added lines?

added lines successed:

```
var form = '<tr id="package_' + data.custom +'">';
                        form += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="donate[package_name]" id="package_name_'+ data.custom +'"  value="" /> </td>';
                        form += '<td>';
                        form += '<select name="settings[currency]" id="currency_'+ data.custom +'" >';
                        form += '<option value="EUR" selected="selected">EUR</option> ';
                        form += '<option value="USD">USD</option>';
                        form += '</select>';
                        form += '</td>';
                        form += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="donate[money]" id="money_'+ data.custom +'"  value="" /></td>';
                        form += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="donate[price]" id="price_'+ data.custom +'"  value="" /></td>';
                        form += '<td>';
                        form += '<select name="settings[pricetype]" id="pricetype_'+ data.custom +'" >';
                        form += '<option value="credits" selected="selected">Credits</option>';
                        form += '<option value="wcoin" >Wcoin</option> ';
                        form += '</select> ';
                        form += '</td>';
                        form += '<td>';
                        form += '<select name="settings[status]" id="status_'+ data.custom +'" >';
                        form += '<option value="1" selected="selected">On</option> ';
                        form += '<option value="1" >Off</option> ';
                        form += '</select> ';
                        form += '</td>';
                        form += '<td><a href="#" class="bg-green" id="save_'+ data.custom +'">Save</a> / <a href="#" class="bg-red" id="remove_'+ data.custom +'">Remove</a></td></tr>';
                        $('#paypal_packages_table').append( form );
```

my ajax post :

```
save_paypal_package: function (unique_id) {

        var package_name    = $('#package_name_'+unique_id).val();
        var currency        = $('#currency_'+unique_id).val();
        var money           = $('#money_'+unique_id).val();
        var price           = $('#price_'+unique_id).val();
        var pricetype       = $('#pricetype_'+unique_id).val();
        var status          = $('#status_'+unique_id).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: MuOnlineWebs.base_url + 'admin-cp/save_paypal_package',
            data: {'type': 'save_paypal_package', unique_id : unique_id, package_name : package_name, currency:currency,money:money,price:price,pricetype:pricetype,status:status},
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                App.display_loader();
            },
            complete: function () {
                App.hide_loader();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.session)
                {
                    App.notifier_box(data.response, data.type, data.error);
                    setTimeout(function () 
                    {
                        location.href = MuOnlineWebs.base_url + 'logged-in';
                    }, 3000);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (data.error) {
                        App.notifier_box(data.response, data.type, data.error);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        App.notifier_box(data.response, data.type, data.success);
                    }
                }   
            }
        });
    }
```

Step 1 : Loaded page -> https://snag.gy/dRZAq4.jpg
Step 2 : add new line -> https://snag.gy/xHKJSN.jpg

I can post values by current packages which loaded with page. but dynamicly added new lines returns nothing. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: added screens on question. When i add new lines dynamicly with javascript, i can not get values from tham

Comment: where you call the `save_paypal_package` function.

Comment: my initalized aplications

Comment: looks like the unique id being passed when calling the function might be wrong. put a breakpoint there and check if the passed id matches that of the item.

Comment: Please add the part where you call it @Dream

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some naming scheme for each element id. Why not just

```
document.getElementById(// your id).value;
```

?

Comment: $('#package_name_'+unique_id).val(); and document.getElementById(id).value; returns nothing i tried both. i can not post new added elements

Comment: Did you console.log what is returned by document.getElementById?